# Asp.NET MVC and Backendless integration/connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, backendless

I'm working on and ASP.NET MVC web application, and I have to connect/integrate the ASP.NET MVC website with Backendless for my backend(databse).
I tried to use firebase, but it didn't work for my mobile app, since it is an integrated system.
So I chose Backendless for my backend side of the system.
I managed to connect the mobile app with Backendless, but I have no clue on how to connect the web application.

I tried to watch videos on YouTube, but I couldn't find any vids that relates to my problem.